# Debugging Stack corruption methods

Tags: c++, windbg, stack-corruption

I'm facing a stack corruption that breakpoints right before at the return of the `wWinMain` function.. can anyone suggest me a way, or some tips of how to debug a stack corruption? (preferably in winDbg)

I know the corruption occurs in a procedure that I wrote in masm for my program, but the stack seems to be fine during the whole procedure. `rsp` register has all it needs during the whole time..

Comment: What is the computing architecture? 64Bit / 32Bit ? What is the size of the process / heap when it dumps the core? close to 4GB?

Comment: Are you following the standard x64 calling convention or using your own custom convention? Are you saving and restoring nonvolatile registers?

Comment: Compile with /RTCs [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Im working in a 64bit architecture, i've moved all the registers that are used in the procedure on the stack, all 8 bytes aligned. once it reaches the ret instruction the stack pointer points to the return address as needed. im processing an array of words (dw) inside the procedure, i guess this has something to do with the corruption its just annoying to trace!

Comment: its not the array handling, I've commented out the whole procedure besides the prolog and epilog. still stack corruption occurs. can I paste the code here somewhere? or it will look creepy with this font and whitespaces

Answer (score 2):

Perform these in order:

- Compile with high level warning, and fix most warnings
- Run Code Analysis on project, and fix the warnings - specially the one that says word about buffer/array/stack etc.
- If the corruption is still is not fixed, reduce the function size (comment out the upper or lower part of function). Don't just `return` - the corrupting stack buffer may still be allocated - commenting out will omit the bad-stack from program code.
- Refactor the `wWinMain` - divide into sub tasks (functions). One of the function will fail because of stack, and you'll locate the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to trace the bug! I've overwritten a variables content by mistake by moving a value to qword ptr[rsp+20h], the 20h(offset) was too far and it overwritten my HINSTANCE variable. :) the stack corruption occurred around the 'instance' variable. managed to trace with the help of WinDbg good practice.

thanks to all the responders.